# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown button not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am beginner to twitter bootstrap and I am trying to create a dropdown button from the samples given in http://getbootstrap.com/ but it doesnt seems to work. please help...
here is my code...

```
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="Button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
                Login As 
                  <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/Home/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Employee">Employee</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Other">Other User</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju_Bollera/DAhU3/)

Comment: When asking a question, you should remove all code not related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include this in your button tag:

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

Answer (score 1):

You mised `data-toggle="dropdown"`

```
<button type="Button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAhU3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

hi dear see this link of jsfddle demo [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DAhU3/6/)

add  library  jquery-1.11.0
     bootstrap.mini.css
     docs.mini.css
     bootstrap.mini.js
     docs.mini.js

**html**

```
 <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand">MySample Login</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <label>UserName</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" />

            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <br />
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    login<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Home/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Employee">Employee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/other">Other User</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="reset">Clear</button>
        </form>
    </div
```

>